# DLookup in Access form not working

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working with a form (Numbers Entry) that inputs information into a table (Numbers).  The first field in the form is a combo box (Property Initials) that allows the user to choose which property he is entering information for.  I am trying to setup a textbox on the form that will provide information (# of Models) from another table (Property Info) based on which property is chosen from the first field, which is the combo box named Property Initials.  I believe `DLookup` is the best way to do this, and have been trying to no avail to get it to work properly.  Currently I am using the following:

```
=DLookUp("[# of Models]","Property Info","Property Initials = " & [Forms]![Numbers Entry]![Property Initials])
```

This returns an `#error` and I've tried about a gazillion different methods and none have worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your suggestion Gustav, with and without the apostrophe in the "Property Initials = ' " and still couldn't get it to work.  It still throws an #Error

Comment: It may be caused by your spaces in the names. See edit.

Comment: Sadly, its still not working and still throwing the #Error.

Comment: I've tried building a query that pulls the information from the table, and then having dlookup reference the query instead, and I still return the same #Error.

Comment: This has to work: =DLookUp("[# of Models]","[Property Info]")     - when confirmed, find some initials you know exists, say JD, and try:   =DLookUp("[# of Models]","[Property Info]","[Property Initials] = 'JD'")  -- it also has to work. If not, something else is going on.

Comment: So both methods you outlined above work.  What am I missing in the criteria portion that won't allow it to use the user defined choice on the form (Property Initials - combo box) as the lookup criteria?  Thanks for all of your help and time thus far!

Comment: Well you solved it!  After trying both methods outlined above to verify that it was working correctly, I retyped in the statement that both of us believed would work, and voila it worked!  Don't ask me why it wasn't working previously.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a string variable, thus:

```
=DLookUp("[# of Models]","[Property Info]","[Property Initials] = '" & [Forms]![Numbers Entry]![Property Initials] & "'")
```